# python typing: mypy warning with multiple return values

Tags: python-3.x, mypy, typing

Using python 3.8 and mypy 1.4.1, I get the mypy warning

```
Expected type 'Dict[str, float]', got 'Dict[str, Tuple[float, float, float]]' instead
```

when using multiple return values (as a tuple) and adding one of them to a dict.

```
from typing import Dict, Tuple

def foo() -> Tuple[float, float, float]:
    return 1, 3, 5

a: Dict[str, float] = {}
a["asdf"], _, _ = foo()
```

Warning is given for `a`.

Comment: You didn't get this warning with mypy, you got it with PyCharm or an IntelliJ IDE. You should file an issue on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/. mypy is fine with this code.

Comment: i just ran this code and dont get any warnings...